# How to add effects on hover to classes that are not child elements?

Tags: css

```
<div class="related_images">
    <img class="related_attachment" src="img url"/>
</div>
<a class="related_title">Stackoverflow</a>
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to add effects to the `.related_attachment` when I hover over the `.related_title` since they aren't child elements.

I've tried the following with no luck..

```
.related_title:hover ~ .related_attachment { opacity: 1; }
.related_title:hover + .related_attachment { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of another question, but no, there's no way to do this currently with CSS.

Comment: No, this is not possible with CSS. You can not target the child of a parent's sibling.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with pure CSS. You may need to mix in JavaScript to accomplish this.